# How to change your personality?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, krishna, yoga

Is there any method mentioned to change your personality coz there are many descriptions how a man should act like but is there any method to change your personality to that

Comment: I think personality is hard to change, comes from lots of past life stuffs ? But some small things you don’t like about yourself, can try for self improvement, no probs. I bet your personality is much better than you think it is by the way. Some stuff I didn’t like about myself turned out to be reaction to extreme/severe psychological abuse. That stuff went away w/ psych help. Maybe google & look up psych articles on things you want to change, tons of info online. Read every article you find, watch Youtoobz vids, TikToks. But I bet your personality is good, you just don’t realize that yet 